# How to find a features within defined radius ---> Postgresql

Tags: gis, geospatial, rdbms, postgresql-9.2, shapefile

I have tables for police stations and polling booths.
Table police station have column (1) gid, (2) Name_police station (3) pin code (4) geom 
Table Polling Booth have column  (1) gid  (2) Booth_name          (3) geom

How can I get the police stations which are within the range of 2km radius of polling the polling booths.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried and what did/didn't work?

Comment: [ST_DWithin](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) is what you are looking for. If you get stuck, post what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks for replying both @EWit and @ John ,i just alter the query     Query is get polling Booths which are within the range of 2 km radius of police station

Comment: (Query)    SELECT DISTINCT ON (police.gid)      police.gid,police.name as police_station_name ,              police.geom as police_geom,                    jaipur_booth.booth_name,                                  jaipur_booth.geom as booth_geom
                                                                                                                                                 FROM  public.police 
  LEFT JOIN public.jaipur_booth ON ST_DWithin(police.geom, jaipur_booth.geom, 3000)
  ORDER BY police.gid, ST_Distance(police.geom, jaipur_booth.geom);

Comment: -----> because i have 44 police station and 3314 polling booths which are close enough so altest 250 polling booth must be in result but there are only 44 booths, 1 for each police_station.